# Como obter o resto de um número float em C?

Tags: c, float

Esta questão é la do URI eu pensei nessa ideia mais quando vou tirar o resto de numeros float não consigo...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int dinheiro)
{
    int res, res2;
```

Aqui eu tenho um array de inteiros que eu acho que deveria ser float para colocar os valores meores.

```
int notas[] = {100, 50, 20, 10, 5 ,2};
float moeda, moedas[] = {1.0, 0.50, 0.25, 0.10, 0.05, 0.01};
scanf("%i", &dinheiro);
printf("NOTAS:\n");
for(int i=0;i<=5; i++)
{
    res = dinheiro / notas[i];
    printf("%d nota(s) de R$ %d.00\n", res, notas[i]);
    dinheiro %= notas[i];
}
```

Até aqui o programa roda e faz a contagem e separação das notas.

Meu problema é quando chega nas moedas...

```
printf("MOEDAS:\n");

moeda = dinheiro;
```

Aqui é o problema, tirar o resto de números float, tanto aqui como na parte das notas.

```
    for(int j=0;j<=6; j++)
    {
        res2 = moeda / moedas[j];
        printf("%i moedas(s) de R$ %.2f\n", res2, moedas[j]);
        moeda = moeda/2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Se alguém tiver uma dica agradeço...

Comment: Aqui um exemplo de como tirar a parte fracionária da variável. `#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

 int i = 0;
 float j = 3.55;
 i = j; // recebe a parte inteira
 j = j - i; //retira a parte inteira e sobra a parte fracionaria
 printf("%d", i);
 printf("\n%f", j);
 return 0;
}`

Comment: Mas o exercício é separar o dinheiro em notas e moedas ? Ou é dizer como ficava uma quantidade de dinheiro, só em notas de 100, só em notas de 50, etc.. ?

Comment: separar o dinheiro...

Answer (score 2):

Você quer separar uma quantia X de dinheiro com o menor número de notas e moedas possíveis.

Como bem notado, a minha resposta anterior tinha problemas já que o `float` é *impreciso*. Refiz o código usando apenas números inteiros, pra evitar esses problemas.

Como tudo é feito utilizando inteiros apenas eu represento todas as notas e moedas em centavos ao invés de utilizar reais. O processo de leitura do dinheiro eu separo em duas, o que tá a esquerda do ponto (parte inteira) e o que tá a direita (parte decimal). Depois junto tudo na variável `dinheiro`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
        int notas[6]={10000,5000,2000,1000,500,200};
        int moedas[6]={100,50,25,10,5,1};
        int inteiro;
        int decimal;
        int dinheiro;

        int n;

        int i;

        scanf("%d.%d", &inteiro, &decimal);

        if(decimal>99){
                printf("Erro, decimal com mais de 2 digitos.\n");
                return -1;
        }

        dinheiro=inteiro*100+decimal;

        printf("Notas:\n");
        for(i=0;i<6;i++){
                n=dinheiro/notas[i];
                dinheiro-=n*notas[i];
                printf("%d nota(s) de R$ %.2f\n", n,notas[i]/100.);
        }

        printf("Moedas:\n");
        for(i=0;i<6;i++){
                n=dinheiro/moedas[i];
                dinheiro-=n*moedas[i];
                printf("%d moeda(s) de R$ %.2f\n", n,moedas[i]/100.);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: É isso, mais seu código fica impreciso quando chega nas moedas de 0.01 centavos. sempre desconta uma...

Comment: É verdade @WesleyAlvesCardoso, o ponto flutuante tava gerando alguns problemas. Refiz tudo sem utilizar `float`, veja se está correto.

Answer (score 0):

Poderia me explicar melhor a pergunta?
Rodei o código assim e me parece ok.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int dinheiro)
{
    int res, res2;
    int notas[] = {100, 50, 20, 10, 5 ,2};
    float moeda, moedas[] = {1.0, 0.50, 0.25, 0.10, 0.05, 0.01};
    scanf("%i", &dinheiro); 
    printf("\n\n\nNOTAS:\n");
    for(int i=0;i<=5; i++)
    {
        res = dinheiro / notas[i];
        printf("%d nota(s) de R$ %d.00\n", res, notas[i]); 

    }
     printf("MOEDAS:\n");


    moeda = dinheiro;


     for(int j=0;j<=5; j++)
    {

       res2 = moeda / moedas[j];

      printf("%i moedas(s) de R$ %.2f\n", res2, moedas[j]);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Entendi o ponto de vista, mais de acordo com que ele separa as notas ele desconta o valor separado:

549.78

5 notas de 100

2 notas de 20

1 nota de 5

2 notas de 2

1 moeda de 0.50

2 moedas de 0.10

1 moeda de 0.05

3 moedas de 0.01